# Sending value back from handler in android

Tags: java, android, android-handler

Hello I am passing handler message from test Service to test activity. Is there any way i can return object from TestActivity to Testservice class. Or is there any easier way to do this.

```
public class TestService {
    public Handler testResultsHandler;

    private BooleanstoreTestResults(String message) {
        if (testResultsHandler != null)

        {
            Message message = testResultsHandler.obtainMessage();
            message.obj = "refresh";
            testResultsHandler.sendMessage(message);
        }
    }
}


public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private TestService testService = new TestService(this);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        formView = (View) findViewById(R.id.form);
        messageTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_message);
        testService.testResultsHandler = new TestResultResponse();

    }

    private class TestResultResponse extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (msg != null && msg.obj != null && this != null) {
                if (msg.obj.toString().equals("refresh")) {
                    refresh(); // return value back to testservice in here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ServiceConnection to store Service handler in Activity.

```
private ServiceConnection mServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    
    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
        // onServiceDisconnected is only called in extreme situations (crashed / killed).
        mBound = false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) { 
        mConnectorSender = new Messenger(service);                  
        mBound = true;
    }
};
```

and bind service like this:

```
mContext.bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

[Here is](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html#exercise_bindlocalservice) a good tutorial from Vogella.

Also it is better to send small messages in msg.arg1 and msg.arg2 params. You can create constant for refresh action and assign it to msg.arg1. It would be better, than sending the Object.